# Conditional Order of JSF Elements

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.3

I have two JSF elements (e.g., an input text, and an image). For some condition (e.g., if a user is logged in), I want the input text to be rendered first. For the opposite condition (e.g., the user is anonymous), I want the image to be rendered first. Is there a way to accomplish that (that can scale to more than just 2 elements)? The only idea I have, which looks hacky, is the following:

```
<h:inputText rendered=#{condition}/>
<h:graphicImage/>
<h:inputText rendered=#{!condition}/>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here

Comment: @JasperdeVries, I rephrased the question. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Sounds like a job for your style sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use CSS to solve this. Roughly it comes down to:

XHTML:

```html
<div class="container input#{condition ? 'First' : 'Last'}">
    <h:inputText/>
    <h:graphicImage/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.container { overflow: auto; }
.container.inputFirst input { float: left; }
.container.inputLast input { float: right; }
```

Again, this is rough. It's just to give you an idea. Customize it to your needs. There are many ways in which you could style this.

If you want to use flex, try:

```css
.container { display: flex; }
.container.inputLast { flex-direction: row-reverse; }
```

Comment: In this day and age I would probably solve it with a flex display type and the CSS order attribute. But whatever, if it works it works.

Comment: @Gimby it's just to give an idea of how to solve it. Added a flex example as well.